# Почему первый запуск LiveWallpaper долгий?

Tags: android, livewallpaper

После установки, первый запуск `LiveWallpaper` очень долгий, а потом все ок. В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 3):

Проблема может быть с Dex-файлами. Андроид закачивает файлы и готовит их к работе.
Попробуйте использовать для сборки проекта [Андроид Студию 1.5.1](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/1-5-1)

У вас будет APK несколько большего размера, за счёт того, что DEX-файлы будут уже скимпилированы внутрь. Зато запуск будет мгновенный.